# Display two nodes related by author in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

We have users who are able to sell products. Products are a cck type. Such users also create a company cck type.

We want to create a view that displays products and the company information that was created by the user who also added the product. The view might look something like.

product 1
$10 per unit

company:
acme products
Atlanta, GA 30304

---

product 2
$15 per unit

company:
John's products
Johnson City, TN 23468

Product 3
$12 per unit

Company:
John's products
Johnson City, TN 23468

It seems like this should be possible using relationships, but I have not been able to figure this out.

Comment: cck is a term that refers to the CCK module for drupal 6. It was included in drupal 7 as fields. I think you mean "Products are a content type". please correct me if I am wrong. Are products a standard content type or are you using a commerce module?

Comment: Yes products are a content type, not part of a commerce module.

Comment: Can a user only have 1 company or many? If a user can only have one company, might it be easier to put the company fields on the user rather than creating another content type?

Comment: The user can only have one company type. However we want a separate type because we want to use location fields and user location might be different from the company.

Comment: I gave it a go and am having trouble outputting how you want it too. Adding a entity reference field on a product that relates to the users company would allow you to get the views output you want quite easily. A view could be used to populate the entity reference field to only show the users company/companies (which would allow a user to have more than one company if needed in the future)